# Was any Medieval state ever "partially" Roman Catholic?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, religion, christianity, catholic-church

It is my understanding that in most of (if not all) the states in western medieval Europe the Roman Catholic church was the only recognized religious body.

I'm looking for an example of a state with recognized Roman Catholic presence (priests and bishops with Papal investiture) but where there was at least one other dominant and recognized religious body (or at least presence if it wasn't as organized).

My understanding of medieval history is pretty basic so it could be that my question is either silly or wrong or both in which case I apologize.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "dominant" and "presence"... France had Cartharism, the Rhine Valley(?) and Croatia had Bogomilist, Italy had Fraticelli, and so on and so on. Also, from the tags I assume you are asking about during the Medieval period, so I took the liberty of editing that in.

Comment: There is always Moorish Spain. Although the reconquista eventually pushed the Moors out, there was in fact quite some time where various provinces had both Roman Catholic and Islamic institutions.

Comment: I suspect you will find active Jewish synagogues in most of the states.  I suspect that you'll also find Islamic institutions in the Balkans for a good portion of the period.

Comment: Per Mark, the question is formed based on incorrect assumptions.  Also there were multiple Papacies and repeated organised "heresy"ies.

Comment: @SamuelRussell Yes, but should you downvote someone for not already knowing what religious minorities existed in the Medieval period? Or choosing to see anti-popes and various heresies as internal to Roman Catholicism?

Comment: I'm voting on a question, not a person, and I regularly change my votes on edited questions.

Comment: and the initial premise that every state (which concept wasn't really prevalent at the time, but that aside) in medieval Europe was Roman Catholic is itself wrong. Not only does the ME stretch over a period including the early reformation, but there's the Greek Orthodox Church, and the Russian Orthodox Church as well (though those two might not have been separate from each other at the time).

Comment: Medieval Spain had Muslims and Jews throughout the middle ages.  There was a least one Muslim mosque in Constantinople for traders, etc. for centuries.  Muslims began to settle in the Balkans after 1355 in the late middle ages.  Some Balkan lands had mixed Catholics and Orthodox communities. There were Muslim communities in the Roman Catholic kIngdom of Sicily for centuries after it was conquered from the Muslims.  Kings who converted to Catholicism didn't manage to convert their entire populations for decades or centuries.

Comment: And the pagan rulers of the Grand duchy of Lithuania ruled over both Catholic and Orthodox populations until converting to Catholicism in the late 14th century.